# EGMU CV 4.5 Face Recognition Prediction Result Not Showing

Tags: .net, vb.net, emgucv

Long story short I was looking around for example code on face recognition using the latest emgucv version 4.5.3 and .net 5 with no luck so I decided to try it on my own.

I've managed to start video capture, load the haarscascades file, load trained faces and labels from file, train new faces and save them with label to file, detect faces on the video capture, show how many faces are being detected, etcetera.

But I'm strugling in getting the name of the person trained drawn when recognized.

Right now its just showing 0 and -1 above the face detected so I'm thinking maybe I messed up the Face Recognizer values or since I had to convert the list of string to list of integer maybe that its what causing the issue.

Any ideas? Here's my code.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim Labelsinfo As String
    Dim Labels__1 As String()
    Dim face As CascadeClassifier
    Dim grabber As VideoCapture
    Dim dstMat As New Mat()
    Dim currentFrame As Image(Of Bgr, [Byte])
    Dim grayFrame As Image(Of Gray, [Byte])
    Dim Frame As Mat
    Dim NumLabels As Integer
    Dim ContTrain As Integer
    Dim t As Integer
    Dim NamePersons As New List(Of String)()
    Dim trainingImages As List(Of Mat) = New List(Of Mat)()
    Dim labels As New List(Of String)()
    Dim pname As EigenFaceRecognizer.PredictionResult
    Dim pnames As String = Nothing
    Dim result As Image(Of Gray, Byte)
    Dim TrainedFace As Image(Of Gray, Byte) = Nothing
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'Start video capture on form load
        grabber = New VideoCapture()
        grabber.Set(CapProp.AutoExposure, 0)
        grabber.QueryFrame()
        Timer1.Start()
    End Sub
    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        'Load haarcascades
        face = New CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
        Try
            'Load trained faces
            Labelsinfo = File.ReadAllText(Application.StartupPath + "/tfcs/tlbls.txt")
            Labels__1 = Labelsinfo.Split("%"c)
            NumLabels = Convert.ToInt16(Labels__1(0))
            ContTrain = NumLabels
            Dim LoadFaces As String
            For tf As Integer = 1 To NumLabels
                LoadFaces = "face" & tf & ".bmp"
                trainingImages.Add(New Mat(Application.StartupPath + "/tfcs/" & LoadFaces))
                labels.Add(Labels__1(tf))

            Next
        Catch e As Exception
            'Error Catch
            MessageBox.Show("Nothing in database, please add a face.", "Trained faces load", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try
            'Trained face counter
            ContTrain = ContTrain + 1

            'Get a gray frame from the videocapture
            Frame = grabber.QueryFrame()
            CvInvoke.Resize(Frame, dstMat, New Size(480, 360), interpolation:=Inter.Cubic)
            grayFrame = dstMat.ToImage(Of Gray, Byte)()

            'Detect faces
            Dim facesdetected As Rectangle() = face.DetectMultiScale(grayFrame, 1.1, 10, New Size(20, 20))

            'Action for each element detected
            For Each facesFound As Rectangle In facesdetected
                TrainedFace = currentFrame.Copy(facesFound).Convert(Of Gray, Byte)()
                Exit For
            Next

            'Resize faces detected
            CvInvoke.Resize(result, TrainedFace, New Size(100, 100), interpolation:=Inter.Cubic)
            trainingImages.Add(TrainedFace.Mat)
            labels.Add(TextBox1.Text)

            'Show face added
            ImageBox2.Image = TrainedFace

            'Write the number of trained faces in a file text for further load
            File.WriteAllText(Application.StartupPath + "/tfcs/tlbls.txt", trainingImages.ToArray().Length.ToString() & "%")

            'Write the labels of trained faces in a file text for further load
            For i As Integer = 1 To trainingImages.ToArray().Length
                trainingImages.ToArray()(i - 1).Save(Application.StartupPath + "/tfcs/face" & i & ".bmp")
                File.AppendAllText(Application.StartupPath + "/tfcs/tlbls.txt", labels.ToArray()(i - 1) + "%")
            Next
            'Show success
            MessageBox.Show(TextBox1.Text + "´s face added", "Training Passed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            TextBox1.Text = ""
            ImageBox2.Image = Nothing

            'Catch error
        Catch
            MessageBox.Show("Training Fail", "Failure!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Label3.Text = "0"

        NamePersons.Add("")
        'Get the current frame from Videocapture
        Frame = grabber.QueryFrame()
        CvInvoke.Resize(Frame, dstMat, New Size(480, 360), interpolation:=Inter.Cubic)
        currentFrame = dstMat.ToImage(Of Bgr, [Byte])
        'Convert it to Grayscale
        grayFrame = currentFrame.Convert(Of Gray, [Byte])()
        'Face Detector
        Dim facedetected As Rectangle() = face.DetectMultiScale(grayFrame, 1.1, 10, New Size(20, 20))
        'Action for each element detected
        For Each faceFound As Rectangle In facedetected
            t = t + 1
            result = currentFrame.Copy(faceFound).Convert(Of Gray, Byte)().Resize(100, 100, Inter.Cubic)
            'Draw rectangle around the face detected
            currentFrame.Draw(faceFound, New Bgr(Color.Green), 2)

            If trainingImages.ToArray().Length <> 0 Then
                'Eigen face recognizer
                Dim recognizer As New EigenFaceRecognizer(3000, 0.001)
                'Convert labels list of string to list of integer
                Dim labelsint As List(Of Integer) = labels.ConvertAll(Of Integer)(Function(ByVal input As String)
                                                                                      Dim data() As String = input.Split(";"c)
                                                                                      Return New Integer()
                                                                                  End Function)
                'Train recognizer
                recognizer.Train(New VectorOfMat(trainingImages.ToArray()), New VectorOfInt(labelsint.ToArray()))
                'Predict result
                pname = recognizer.Predict(result)

                'Draw the label for each face recognized
                CvInvoke.PutText(currentFrame, pname.Label, New Point(faceFound.X - 2, faceFound.Y - 2), FontFace.HersheyTriplex, 0.5, New MCvScalar(255, 255, 0), 2)
            End If
            grayFrame.Dispose()

            NamePersons(t - 1) = pname.Label
            NamePersons.Add("")

            Label3.Text = facedetected.Length.ToString()

        Next
        t = 0

        'Names concatenation
        For nnn As Integer = 0 To Convert.ToInt32(Label3.Text) - 1
            pnames = pnames + NamePersons(nnn) + ", "
        Next
        'Show the faces procesed and recognized
        ImageBox1.Image = currentFrame
        Label5.Text = pnames
        pnames = ""
        'Clear the list(vector) of names
        NamePersons.Clear()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Ok so in earlier emgu cv versions the labels you feed to get a prediction were the actual names as string. Now from version 3.1 I think, you need to feed integers. So what I did was to feed the index integers from the labels list to train them and get a prediction. The result gives me a number which I then index again to the labels list to get a name. This seem to work but I need to test with more faces. Also I'm getting some out of index errors that need to be worked out.